# need help with mysql for book system - problem with where clause

Tags: sql

hello all im developing new project for publisher ...this project for develop system saved all books for that publisher ...............
we have 3 table 
books
author
coauthor

problem case:
ieach book have 1 main author thats author could replay in alot of books and ieach book in some cases could have co-author this co author could be 1 or 2 or 3 or 12 note: this co author is already saved in author table

realtionship:
one to many between authors and books

many to many between coauthor and books and authors

table #1 authors table => table hold all authors 
id - author_name

table #2 books table => table hold all books
id- title - author_id - publishing_year

table #3 co_authors table => hold all item which have alot of co author
item_id and authors_id

now how i can retrive all books for specific author if he is main author or co author

Comment: `co_authors.item_id` maps to `books.book_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two ways you can go about this... One is to use a `UNION`, so something like:

```
SELECT id FROM books WHERE author_id = ?
UNION ALL
SELECT item_id FROM co_authors WHERE authors_id = ?
```

Another way you could solve this is to rework your database structure such that there is no author_id in the books table and instead you have a flag in co_authors called main_author or some such. Considering you may have books where it's unclear who the main author is, this may make more sense...

Comment: You can also do this with left join

Comment: @Krtek, assuming you want the main author as well. Otherwise you'd have extra information in your result set. Also, if you're not careful, you'll end up with a row for each co-author of a book that the author in question is the main author of.

Comment: @jswolf19 take a look at my query, it does the job without any problems you're mentioning.

Comment: @Krtek, acutally, with your query, if the author in question is the main author of a book with multiple co-authors, then, yes, a row will be returned for each co-author of the book.

Comment: @jswolf19 no, the where clause will only select the row with the given author id, you can try it ;)

Comment: @Krtek, I did try it, just to be sure. You should, too. If the author you want is the books.author_id, and that book.id appears in x rows in the co_authors table, then you will get results for that book x times.

Comment: shit, you're right... I added a distinct to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT books.*, authors.*
FROM books
LEFT JOIN co_authors ON co_authors.item_id = books.id
INNER JOIN authors ON 
        authors.id = books.author_id OR 
        authors.id = co_authors.author_id
WHERE authors.id = ID
```

The `where` clause can also be written where `authors.name = 'NAME'` if you need to search by name and not id.

EDIT: added distinct to avoid multiple rows for the same book.